# Binary fields in code-first migrations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Regards,

I have problems with migrations and binary fields...

My initial migration looks like this (I had an existing database):

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable("dbo.Words", c => new
    {
        ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
        Name = c.String(maxLength: 4000),
        Image = c.Binary(),
        Audio = c.Binary(),
    }).PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);
}
```

And the Entity class is here:

```
public class Word
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength]
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    [MaxLength]
    public byte[] Audio { get; set; }
}
```

I have automatic migrations turned on.
Now if I drop all the tables from the database and run "Update-Database" I get:

```
Applying code-based migration: 201304211813502_InitialMigration.
Applying automatic migration: 201304212024538_AutomaticMigration.
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException (0x80004005): Cannot alter column of type NTEXT or IMAGE [ Column Name = Image ]
```

So it looks like something is not in sync.. I run "Add-Migration AutoMigration" to see what entity framework had in mind it has to still be updated... The file I get is here:

```
public partial class AutoMigration: DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Words", "Image", c => c.Binary());
        AlterColumn("dbo.Words", "Audio", c => c.Binary());
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Words", "Audio", c => c.Binary(maxLength: 4000));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Words", "Image", c => c.Binary(maxLength: 4000));
    }
}
```

So... from this it looks like EF thinks Image and Audio fields are Binary(maxLength: 4000).. but they're not supposed to be!! (because in the initial migration they are **Binary()**).

So I'm stuck and cannot get up-to-date with my migrations... and I need MaxLength (unlimited) binary fields...

What could be going on here?
thank you!
david

Comment: Can you please help somehow? I wanted to try if this works in EF 6 alpha3, but have problems compiling the code...:


`Error 11 The type or namespace name 'Column' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` 
`Error 3 The type or namespace name 'MaxLength' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` 


I include:

`using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`
`using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;`

Where have those attribute defnitions moved?

thank you!

Comment: grrr. so buggy... after VS restart the project compiles... but I don't see any packages installed in nuget package manager.. I cannot add migrations because it says no packages are installed.. when I try to isntall EF again, I get: `PM>  Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre
'EntityFramework 6.0.0-alpha3' already installed.
'packages.config' already exists. Skipping...
Successfully added 'EntityFramework 6.0.0-alpha3' to Logo.`

and then:


`PM> Add-Migration AutoMigration
No packages installed.
The EntityFramework package is not installed on project 'Logo'.`

Comment: Make sure to select the  correct target project when running migrations from the PM console, as they rely on access to the config file with the cpnnection string

Comment: Don't quite understand what you're saying.... how do I select the correct target project... and why is there no EntityFramework among the installed packages? I found another strange bug... I reverted the project to EF5 and tried to uninstall the package and then install it again and of course it didn't add the reference to EntityFramework.dll. This was missing from the csproj file: `<Reference Include="EntityFramework">      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath></Reference>`.. just riddled with bugs :S

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to upgrade the project to EF 6.0.0 Alpha3 ... I had to fix a lot of small problems and also upgrade NuGet to 2.5 RC. Now it works.. not sure what I did but most likely it was just an upgrade to EF 6